# How to position view in this ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want the `ImageView` positioned to the far right

look at the picture the first row have a white color `ImageView` how to make it stick to the right. Using the Android layout inspector the `ImageView` show to have empty space on both right and left side. Is there some Gravity left something I can use?

[image]

Here´s the XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="?AppTheme.line_box_background_1">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.74"/>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="?AppTheme.list_item_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline567"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline67"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline5654"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_extra"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5654"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_create_port_place"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textColor="?AppTheme.PrimaryTextColor"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_extra"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:text="some text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_extra"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="?AppTheme.PrimaryTextColor"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_content"
            tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
            tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
            tools:text="some text"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_street_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline567"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_google_place"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline567"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline32"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_street_image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/powered_by_google_on_white"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_flag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline521"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline67"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_circle"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline67"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.17"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline567"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.89"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_country"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="country"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline567"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline67"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline521"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012"/>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline521"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.4"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using ConstraintLayout I find it better to preview in blueprint mode. If you do so you'll be able to see the circle indicating the constraints in each element:

[image]

TO use it just click and drag the arrow to the view you want this element to me constrained to. In you case you'll use the top and right constraints guides to position the image view to the top right in the screen.

Moreover, to have a parfectly squared image view you should set the width and height to be the sabe, if you have wrap content in one and 0dp in other it won't be perfectly squared but rather rectangular because one of the dimensions is allowed to grow freely.

Comment: I use the Android Studio layout designer. If I as as you say set width and height the same like 20db, that would work but would not look nice on different devices

Comment: Then try wrapping content in both dimensions, or setting both to 0dp. But if u do the latter you'd need to constrain all four sides of the image view.

Comment: But i tried it, the top was constraint to `guideline5654` (50% vertical)and if I then constraint all 4 sides of the `ImageView` the` ImageView` end up in the middle not to the right,

Comment: After u do that, what happens if you grab the image view and position where you want it?

Comment: I set 0dp for width and height and constraint all siden then there´s no way to movie it with the mouse, it stay centered

Comment: On the right side in the designer there´s a bar 0-100 for horizontal, that has no effect

Comment: I see. The problem is that it will grow to clip to the constrained view, that's why you can't move. Try setting the dimensions to a value or to wrap content and check if you can move the view around with the mouse. I know you don't want to set a fixed number, but do it just to test it out

Comment: If I set width to 20dp then the ImageView can be position to the right. Maybe I have to live with that

Comment: I see no other way, but by using"dp" it should look roughly the same in most devices

Comment: yea maybe Thanks Levi, it´s also a VectorDrawable highly scalable I read